# Connecting To Restful WCF Web Service and Jquery Mobile/HTML

Tags: html, jquery, rest, jquery-mobile

I have created a small web application which i am trying to connect to my web service. For some reason, i am receiving the error '200'.

The functionality is simple:
**1**) The user enters a value (product number) on the Home.html page.
**2**) The service is called and performs a search based on the value entered.
**3**) If a result is found, output the product number on the SearchResult.html page.

**Home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]>    <html class="no-js iem7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#222222">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>    
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js">    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <header class="Navigation">            
        <div class="headerImage"><img src="images/logo-small.png" alt="Home"/</div>        
    </header>

    <div id="product" class="Banner">
        Product Search
    </div>

       <br />
        <div class="nine-tenths">
            Please enter a product number.
        </div>

            <input id="productNum" class="productNum" type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Number"/>           

        <br />                                 

        <button type="button" id="btnSearch" onclick="btnSearch()">Search</button>   

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.JS**

```
function btnSearch() {
//  document.location.href = 'SearchResult.html';

var productNum= $("#productNum").val(); 
alert(productNum);

var ajaxSearch = "http://localhost:8008/Product/ProductList/GetProduct.php?prod_num?" + productNum;
alert(ajaxSearch);

$.ajax(ajaxSearch,

{
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    // $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
},

complete: function () {
// $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    //alert(thrownError);
},
success: function (data) {
    var result = data.GetEmployeeListingResult;

    $.each(result, function (index, output) {
        $('#EmployeeList').append('<li> <a href=SearchResult.html?productNum=' + output.prod + '> </a>   .....</li>');
    });

    //$('#EmployeeList').listview('refresh');
}
});
```

}

**SearchResult.html**

```
<table style="width:100%;" class="searchResultFound">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%;">
                <img src="images/resultFound.png" align="left">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productNum" type="text" class="no-outline " disabled="disabled" value="">
                <label>Was found</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width:100%;" class="searchResultNotFound">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%;">
                <img src="images/resultNotFound.png" align="left">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productNum" type="text" class="no-outline " disabled="disabled" value="">
                <label>Was not found</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have tried using this site as an example (why you may see references to Employee's):

http://wrvishnu.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/step-by-step-tutorial-restful-wcf-web-service-and-jquery-mobile/

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add you server side PHP code? I would like to see have you understand how jsonp works.

Answer (score 0):

declaration of URL is wrong in main.js.. 'prod_num',

use "'GetProduct.php?prod_num=' + productNum"

instead of "'GetProduct.php?prod_num?' + productNum"

try using this:

```
var ajaxSearch = "http://localhost:8008/Product/ProductList/GetProduct.php?prod_num=" + productNum;
```

Comment: Thanks. In my main.js file, am i loading the result page correctly?

Comment: it depends on the structure of the result you are getting. you can add view the result by adding breakpoint in the code..
also, if suggested answer helps you, plz 'up' it..

Comment: it depends on the structure of the result you are getting. you can add view the result by adding 'debugger' in the code.. i.e.

var result = data.GetEmployeeListingResult;
debugger;
$.each(result, function (index, output) {
        $('#EmployeeList').append('<li> <a href=SearchResult.html?productNum=' + output.prod + '> </a>   .....</li>');
});